# Exit my while loop at a specific day and time

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a while loop that will be continually processing information over the weekend.  On Monday at 8:00 am I would like this process to stop.

I have this running inside my while loop:

```
 DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
 if (currentDate .DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
 {
      runLoop = false;
 }
```

This should correctly stop my loop as soon as it turns to Monday right?

How do I enable it to continue until 8:00 am on Monday morning?

Comment: Well what's going to *start* your loop again at all? You haven't really given us much context here.

Comment: I will start it manually on Friday when I leave for work.  And I need it to exit gracefully on Monday at 8:00 am before I come into work.

Comment: Ah, I'd misread. (I thought you wanted it to stop at the start of Monday, and then restart at 8am.) Hang on - it's nice and simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me like it's as simple as:

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
if (currentDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday && currentDate.Hour >= 8)
{
     runLoop = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could use `DateTime.Compare`

```
if (DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, Convert.ToDateTime("8:00:00 AM")) >= 0 && DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
{
    loop = false;
}
```